# Sum of ArrayList using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, csv, arraylist, sum

How can I calculate the sum of a specific row in my ArrayList below. So I have had a look on Stack overflow already, and most examples have a double in their for loop. However, I have used a String array so I am not sure how i could calculate the sum of row[9].

```
  try{
        //store csv file into arraylist
         ArrayList<String> searchProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        readData = new ArrayList<>();
        CSVReader br = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        readData = br.readAll();


         //skip first value of arraylist
       for(String[] row:readData.subList(1, readData.size()) ) {
      searchProducts.add(row[9]);
        System.out.println("saved: " + row[9]);


    }



    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you would like to fix your indentation so your code is easier to read.

Comment: What is the sum of strings supposed to be? Concatenating all of them together? Also what have you tried doing - your provided code does nothing with the `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy with the Stream API:

```
int sum = searchProducts.stream()
                        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                        .sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int sum = 0;
for(String str:searchProducts){
 sum+=Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

without stream api

Comment: because I am using a String array, the parse Int method will not work for me.